# What is the best way to handle CSS's width of 5% and 35% becoming 30.5 and 213.5 and IE 7 "round them up" and push the 2nd floated element down?

Tags: css

Very simply, there are 2 divs inside a div with 610px width

1) div1 has width of 60% of parent = 366px, `padding-right` = 5% = 30.5px
2) div2 has width of 35% of parent = 213.5px

**both divs are floated left** inside of parent div.

So on most browsers, they all float inside on the same level, because 366 + 30.5 + 213.5 = 610px, and I am suspecting Firefox, Chrome, and IE 8/9 actually truncate 30.5 to 30 and 213.5 to 213, so the 2 divs ended up a little bit narrow in the parent div, but it isn't a big issue, really, to be 1 or 2 pixels off.

The big issue is with IE 7, that it round up 30.5 to 31, and 213.5 to 214, and now, the total space needed = 611px and therefore div2 cannot float on the same level, and need to be pushed down.  (floated below div1)

What is the best way to handle this?  I am tempted to just change 5% to 4.9%, and 35% to 34.9%, and actually, I think I probably need to change one of them, because the only issue is when both happen to be ending with `.5`, so if one is "lessened" a little bit, then the .4 and .5 will have the effect of one getting rounded down, and one rounded up on IE 7.  But doesn't this affect the result on FF/Chrome/IE 8 and 9 as well?  What is the best or most elegant solution for this, to work in IE 7 to 9 and all other major browsers?

Comment: can't you just set one to 31 and the other to 213? doing decimal on percentage had never yielded good results for me either cross browser.

Comment: @robx my manager did that and I think his motivation was to do a 60% and 35% split, so no matter what the parent's width is, the ratio is the same...  so that's a good way to think about it too.  We are using SASS so we can really use a variable for the parent width and do the math ourselves and do the truncate ourselves using SASS's math function, but that's kind of an overkill to set a variable like that

Comment: Wish I could help, but Know nothing about SASS.

Comment: @動靜能量 In this case I might think rounding up in middle point is good behaviour.

Comment: @robx SASS is really simple... the idea is that you can set a variable, such as `$info_panel_width` to be 610, and you can do math with it, and round up or down as you wish, that's it

Comment: @r.piesnikowski but as I said, both rounded up and made the total width to be 1 pixel wider that the parent div can fit

Comment: I just read through all the comments and, IMHO, the best solution I saw was in your question. I think it is the most elegant and simple solution. I have had this problem before but didn't realize why it was happening so thanks for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need pixel precision for your on screen rendering, you need to specify pixel precision in your widths.

What is the benefit of specifying percentages within a fixed pixel width parent container? Percents are only meaningful within a context of parent containers that also have some form of relative sizing, such as percents.

You should change div1 to width of 366px and padding-right of 30px, and div2 to a width of 214px.

If you are limited to only specifying percentages for some reason, then yes, you can specify extra decimal points in your percentages to get the calculations correct. Drop them by .1 or .2% until the largest ones consistently round down to the right pixel sizes.

As an alternative, you can remove the padding-right from div1 and float div2 to the right instead of to the left.

Comment: I think the statement that "Percents are only meaningful within a context of parent containers that also have some form of relative sizing, such as percents." might need adjustment, because what if the parent is indeed a percentage as well, and the body of the page (adjusted by the user resizing the window) happen to make that parent div 610px?  In the end, everything percentage do become a number when rendered.

Comment: Right, but my point is that regardless of the parent sizing, you cannot expect pixel precision unless you specify pixels. If you specify anything other than pixels for sizing, you are immediately giving up precision in your design because you're working with relative units. Even with pixel units you're still hoping that browsers render consistently.

Comment: I really don't expect pixel precision... I only expect the floated elements don't get pushed down

Comment: Have you considered simply floating div2 to the right and removing padding-right on div1?

Comment: @Jordon that's a good solution too...  although usually I prefer to float everything to the left because floating some elements left and some right do have slightly different behavior sometimes in different browsers.

Comment: If SASS is as simple as just doing math with a variable, the simplest solution is to floor one, and ceil (round up) the other to precision px?

Comment: If you have a parent container for div1 and div2, and the last-most div is floated right, the behaviour is consistent across browsers. The only real kicker is that you won't have an actual element covering 5% of the inside of the container, so background colors may have to be faked.

Comment: I can't remember when it behaved weird... maybe it was on IE 6, that if you float right first and then float another element left, then it behaved differently on IE 6 vs other browsers... something like that...

Comment: That's quite possible. Generally in source order, all of your elements would be floated left first, and then the last one would float right. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use some javascript:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7)
{
    $('.parent').width($('.parent').width() + 1);//Makes parent 1px wider in IE 7
}
```

[Take a look in width() reference.](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: Javascript!  what if the user turned off Javascript, and... the page has to render once and then have Javascript fix the width issue and the page will adjust again?   Also, probably don't want to widen the parent because what if the parent can be pushed down as well... if it is floated also.

Comment: You've got right. It might happen. So another way you can do a separate css for IE 7 and use conditional css comments to load css for IE 7 only and make 1px wider divs. 
`<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a conditional CSS comment...

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
div2 { width: 34.99% }
<![endif]-->
```

or if that failed to work, force a clear and then use relative positioning to put the divs in the correct spot.

```
<div style="width:500px; height:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000">
        <div style="float:left; width:30%; height:100px; background-color:#ddd"></div>    
        <div style="float:left; clear:both; position:relative; left:30%; top:-100px; width:5%; height:100px; background-color:#bbb"></div>
        <div style="float:left; clear:both; position:relative; right:-35%; top:-200px; width:65.5%; height:100px; background-color:#999"></div>
</div>
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/HE8uX/3/

(This should display correctly in IE7. To make sure that the three divs stays within the confines of the parent div, you can check this revision: http://jsfiddle.net/HE8uX/5/  -- the combined width of the three divs should match the width of the black parent)

Comment: clearing and using relative position to do it?  it is more hacky that 34.9%!

Comment: +1 for the relative positioning solution. I use this in production and it works perfect.

Comment: please see: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-liquid-layout-no-quirks-mode